# pessoal estou tentando fazer uma input do tipo text, e o que eu digitar nela quero jogar dentro de uma variavel?

Tags: input

```
<input id="a_input" type="text" >
```

var b = document.getElementById('a_input').innerText = '';

//tem como vcs fazerem retornar pra mim o que eu digitei na input em forma de alert pra ficar mais facil ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não use `innerText`, use `value`:

```
var b = document.getElementById('a_input').value;
alert(b);
```

Usamos `innerText` para objetos que podem ter conteúdo em `html`,  como `div` e `span`, para obter o conteúdo texto, e se quiser o conteúdo em html, `innerHTML`

Comment: mano esqueçir de dizer do botão rs
que quando eu clicar nele o valor vai pro alert

Comment: dai você precisa adicionar um *listener* para acompanhar o evento "onfocus", que acontece quando o campo receber o foco, ou seja, depois de clicar nele ou navagar nele por TAB, e pode fazer, da forma mais simples de entender, assim: `<input id="a_input" type="text" onfocus="alert(this.value)" >`